# Same-origin policy bypass in local enviroment

Tags: php, apache, api, gruntjs

I'm developing a SPA that runs on `Backbone.js` locally and setting server up with Grunt for `livereload` .  I did a REST api with PHP for my app which i also run locally. Now i have a problem with cross domain policy since my servers are on different ports. I tried to combine two servers on one port both from apache and from grunt but i'm not sure if it is at all possible. How should i deal with this problem? i would like to develop my app locally and use the `livereload` features of grunt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i ended up using [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) which did just what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I propose installing nginx to act as reverse proxy. It can serve static files from one directory (aka frontend), and server side generated scripts (aka backend) from other server.
It serves backend, if the request do not corresponds to the file existing in frontend directory.

This is config example for it - https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/examples/serverConfigsExamples/nginx.conf

It serves static html, css, js files from directory `/home/nap/static` and backend from the `localhost:3000`, and both of them are accessible on localhost:80 as the one server.

I hope this is what you need.